# react stateless component to class component syntax

Tags: reactjs, syntax, components

I just upgraded react from v15.6.2 to v 16.5.2 and now I am getting a few errors along the lines of...

> Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.

After searching for an answer, it looks like I need to convert some stateless components to class components. My problem is with the syntax. If I have the following component, how would I convert it to a class component?

```
const CategoryForm = Form.create()(
  (props) => {
    const { visible, onCancel, onSubmit, form } = props;
    const { getFieldDecorator } = form;
    return (
      <Modal
        visible={visible}
        title="Create New Category"
        okText="Create"
        onCancel={onCancel}
        onOk={onSubmit}
      >
        {this.renderForm(getFieldDecorator)}
      </Modal>
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const CategoryForm = Form.create()(class extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { visible, onCancel, onSubmit, form } = this.props;
    const { getFieldDecorator } = form;

    return (
      <Modal
        visible={visible}
        title="Create New Category"
        okText="Create"
        onCancel={onCancel}
        onOk={onSubmit}
      >
        {this.renderForm(getFieldDecorator)}
      </Modal>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried that but I am getting an error... `ReferenceError: props is not defined`

Comment: All good... had to make some changes (props ->  this.props) and had to move renderForm function in to the CategoryForm component. Thanks